# Java Swing JComboBox remove LAF

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, look-and-feel

How can I remove the LAF style from a Swing `JComboBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't actually *remove* the LAF since then nothing would be rendered but you can set another LAF for that combobox only.

Something like this:

```
combo.setUI( new BasicComboBoxUI() );
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check [*Customizing a JComboBox Look and Feel*](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJComboBoxLookandFeel.htm). Maybe you will find the required answer.